# Getting a notification when a website becomes online

Tags: monitoring, notification, web

I am looking for a program, web browser extension or website service that can give me some notifications (e.g., email or pop-up) whenever a website isn't down anymore.

Any price, license, web browser and operating system is fine.

---

Use case: I have to prepare some tax form through https://www.glaciertax.com/, and the website is currently down. I would like to receive a notification whenever it is back online.

[image: Error message: 'This site can’t be reached']

I am aware of https://www.downnotifier.com however one can only set a notification when the website becomes off-line and not the contrary:

[image: Interface of DownNotifier.com]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://redd.it/65jjh1
- http://qr.ae/T5E6aP

Comment: IIUC, why not just ping the site in regular intervals, say every 10 seconds? Would it be enough? Very easy do to on `*nix`.

Comment: Well, one more thing - if it happens that `ping` works but the site is still not accessible then one should come up with a bit more sophisticated solutions using `wget` or `curl` to directly try to communicate with a remote server using `http` protocol - also easy I think.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

A simple `POSIX compliant` shell script.  I tested it with both `GNU` and
`busybox` versions of `wget` and in `bash` and `ash`.  It opens a
connection every 10 seconds and exits when a connection is
established.  It informs the user that the website is up by displaying
a message box using `zenity` framework.

Alternatively, instead of using `zenity` it could send an e-mail using
`sendmail`, `msmtp` or something similar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# check-up.sh: continously check if website passed in $1 is up using
#              wget and inform user when it's up with zenity

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    printf "Pass website address as the first parameter\n"
    exit 1
fi

command -v zenity >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
    { printf "Please install zenity first\n"; exit 1;}

command -v wget >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
    { printf "Please install wget first\n"; exit 1;}

while true
do
    if wget -q -O - "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 10
done

zenity --info  --text="$1 is online"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

[Uptimerobot](https://blog.uptimerobot.com/new-feature-advanced-notification-options-for-the-pro-plan/) - Their Pro Plan appears to be able to do this. I use their free service for monitoring prospective clients web hosting accounts as a sales tool later

Answer (score 1):

This website (still in alpha, and not sure if it works all good) should give you a pop-up when a site comes back online:
http://alpha.itsback.at

It is also on GitHub here https://github.com/aardvarks/itsback.at